# Scala companion objects are not singleton

Tags: scala, singleton, companion-object

I have following two classes.

```
class A (name: String) {
}

object A {
}
```

According to definition of Singleton, we can have only one object of that type. However I am able to create two different objects of type `A` using following piece of code.

```
object B {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val a = new A("Vinod")
     println(a)

     val b = new A("XYZ")
     println(b)
  }
}
```

can someone please explain me, where my understanding is not correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `object` by itself *is* a singleton. It has its own class and no other instance of the same class exist at runtime.

However, the pattern you describe here is different: `object A` is *not* an instance of class `A` unless you make it so using `object A extends A`. You could make it the only instance of class `A` by making class `A` a `sealed` class, but this is unnecessary in almost all cases.

If you really want the singleton pattern, drop the `class` and use only `object A`, all of its members will be "static" in the sense of Java.

Note that the actual type of `object A` can be referred to as `A.type`, which by default is completely unrelated to type `A` if class `A` exists. Again, `A.type` *could* be a subtype of `A` if you explicitly make it so.

Answer (score 4):

The companion object is not an instance of the companion class. They're not even the same type.

```
class A
object A {
  var state = 0
  def update() :Unit = state = state + 1
}

val abc :A = new A   //instance of class A
val xyz :A.type = A  //2nd reference to object A

// both reference the same singleton object
xyz.update()  //res0: Unit = ()
A.state       //res1: Int = 1
abc.state     //Error: value state is not a member of A$A2521.this.A
```

Comment: Nice example, I got the point you want to convey :) Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

the companion object can be thought of as the static space of a class. if you want to make A a singleton you can make it an object rather than a class

Comment: I understand the usecase of companion object. The thing is it violates the definition of singleton. Isn't is true?

Comment: No the companion object of A is not of type A itself. the companion object is indeed a singleton. This can be a bit confusing but makes actually sense. you can `implicitly[A.type =:= A] ` and see that it won't find an instance. A.type is the type of the companion object of A

Comment: I got that. I understood the code provided by @jwvh. Thanks for the help and making my understanding bit clear :)

Answer (score 0):

`new A` refers to `class A` (which is not a singleton), not to `object A`. You can easily check it: if you remove `class A`, the `new A` lines will no longer compile.

Also note that `object`s aren't *necessarily* singletons: they can be nested inside classes or traits, in this case there is one for each instance of the outer type.

Comment: This is slightly misleading IMHO. Objects *are* singletons, because they have their own type. If object `O` is nested in class `C`, and you have an instance `c` of `C`, then the type of the object is `c.O.type` and there is no other instance of this type.

Comment: "_The_ type" is problematic in Scala. 1. `c` is also the only instance of `c.type`. 2. All `O`s should in principle have a common type (other than the supertype of `O`). It doesn't seem to be writable in Scala: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687591/does-scala-have-syntax-for-projection-of-a-nested-singleton-type but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be.

Comment: I agree with you, except the true "type" corresponding to `O` is compiler generated and so `O.type` is the only type for `O` that the code has access to. This is not the case for `c` where we can use `C` for all instances, and `c.type` if we need to refer to `c` in particular.