# Does Scala have syntax for projection of a nested singleton type?

Tags: scala

```
class C {
  object O
}

val x: C#O.type = (new C).O // error: ';' expected but '.' found
val y: C#(O.type) = (new C).O // error: identifier expected but '(' found
```

Is there a legal syntax for this type?

EDIT:

```
val x: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } = (new C).O
```

gives

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:4: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ScalaFiddle.this.C#O.type
 required: c.type#O.type forSome { type c.type <: ScalaFiddle.this.C with scala.this.Singleton{} }
  val x: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } = (new C).O
                                                 ^
```

So Scala compiler understands this type and shows it as `C#O.type`. It seems this case was just overlooked when creating the grammar.

Comment: May I ask what the use case of this syntax? The object `O` is different for each instance of `C`, so why should it be `object` in the first place?

Comment: It's used when you want exactly one `O` for each `C`.

Comment: Can it be achieved the same way with `class O` and `class C { final val o: O = new O }`? There's exactly one `o` for each `C`, and `final val` will guarantee that derived classes can't modify this field.

Comment: `val x: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } = { val c = new C; c.O }` works, because `c` is stable, whereas `(new C)` is not. Wouldn't this be at least a temporary workaround?

Comment: Found interesting sentence in the spec: *"For other expressions e, e.x is typed as if it was { val y = e; y.x }, for some fresh name y."* With this sentence, I don't understand why `{ val c = new C; c.O }` and `(new C).O` are not equivalently. Added an edit to my answer with more details and links.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, and it does seem like a divergence between spec and compiler. I'll ask on the Scala mailing list tomorrow.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin https://users.scala-lang.org/t/a-possible-divergence-from-spec-in-typing-of-new-c-o/2610

Answer (score 4):

**Overview**

1. A few attempts to write down the type
2. A bash script that lists every attempt together with a somewhat cleaned up error message
3. Edit 2018-04-11: Shouldn't the rhs be typed as `{ val y = new C; y.O }`?

---

I can't prove that it is *impossible*, but at least I wanted to make sure that I didn't give up without trying.
It's not really an answer, rather a list of failed attempts, maybe someone
finds it amusing, maybe someone finds the script (in the second part) for generating the list of error messages useful for reporting their findings...

---

**A few attempts to write down the type**

Systematic rewriting of AlexeyRomanov's attempt that looked most promising:

```
val o: x.O.type forSome { val x: C } = (new C).O
val o: x.type#O.type forSome { val x : C } = (new C).O
val o: t#O.type forSome { type t <: C with Singleton } = (new C).O
```

Some more or less unsystematic attempts with type-lambda like constructs:

```
// boring, does nothing, identity, just to recall lambda-syntax
val o: ({ type R <: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } })#R = (new C).O
val o: ({type L[A <: C] = c.O.type forSome { val c: A }})#L[c.type forSome{val c: C}] = (new C).O
val o: ({type L[A <: C] = c.O.type forSome { val c: A }})#L[A forSome {type A <: C}] = (new C).O
```

Experiment with nested `forSome`:

```
val o: x.type forSome { val x: c.O.type forSome { val c: C }} =  (new C).O
```

Experiments with additional type members in `C`:

```
class C {
  object O
  type T = O.type
}

val o: C#T = (new C).O
```

This actually compiles, but modifies the right hand side, so I guess it doesn't count:

```
val o: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } = { val c = new C; c.O }
```

**Conclusion: Looks impossible to me.**

---

**Bash script that generates all the error messages**

To generate all the error messages (without file paths and feature warnings), 
save the part of the post above this line as
`saved_post.txt`, and then run the following script in the same directory:

> Disclaimer: this script actually modifies files in your file system. Please make sure that you really understand what it does, and really *want* to run it, before running it. In particular, it destroys the file 'newCdotO.scala'.

```
#!/bin/bash

tempFile=newCdotO.scala
inputFile=saved_post.txt
grep -oE "^ *val o:.*$" $inputFile | \
while read codeLine
do
  printf '=%.0s' {0..80}
  echo ""
  echo "" > $tempFile
  echo "import scala.language.existentials" >> $tempFile
  echo "import scala.language.higherKinds" >> $tempFile
  echo "class C { object O; type T = O.type }" >> $tempFile
  echo "$codeLine" | tee -a $tempFile
  printf -- '-%.0s' {0..80}
  echo ""
  scala $tempFile 2>&1 | sed 's|^.*error:|error:|g'
done |
awk '{print "    "$0}'
```

This generates the following wall of error messages (Hey, I've tried to clean it up!):

```
=================================================================================
val o: x.O.type forSome { val x: C } = (new C).O
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.C#O.type
 required: x.O.type forSome { val x: this.C }
val o: x.O.type forSome { val x: C } = (new C).O
                                               ^
one error found
=================================================================================
val o: x.type#O.type forSome { val x : C } = (new C).O
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error: ';' expected but '.' found.
val o: x.type#O.type forSome { val x : C } = (new C).O
               ^
one error found
=================================================================================
val o: t#O.type forSome { type t <: C with Singleton } = (new C).O
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error: ';' expected but '.' found.
val o: t#O.type forSome { type t <: C with Singleton } = (new C).O
          ^
one error found
=================================================================================
val o: ({ type R <: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } })#R = (new C).O
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.C#O.type
 required: AnyRef{type R <: c.type#O.type forSome { type c.type <: this.C }}#R
val o: ({ type R <: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } })#R = (new C).O
                                                                 ^
one error found
=================================================================================
val o: ({type L[A <: C] = c.O.type forSome { val c: A }})#L[c.type forSome{val c: C}] = (new C).O
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.C#O.type
 required: c.type(in type L)#O.type forSome { type c.type(in type L) <: c.type(in value o) forSome { type c.type(in value o) <: this.C with Singleton } with Singleton }
val o: ({type L[A <: C] = c.O.type forSome { val c: A }})#L[c.type forSome{val c: C}] = (new C).O
                                                                                                ^
one error found
=================================================================================
val o: ({type L[A <: C] = c.O.type forSome { val c: A }})#L[A forSome {type A <: C}] = (new C).O
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.C#O.type
 required: c.O.type forSome { val c: A forSome { type A <: this.C } }
val o: ({type L[A <: C] = c.O.type forSome { val c: A }})#L[A forSome {type A <: C}] = (new C).O
                                                                                               ^
one error found
=================================================================================
val o: x.type forSome { val x: c.O.type forSome { val c: C }} =  (new C).O
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.C#O.type
 required: x.type forSome { val x: c.type#O.type forSome { type c.type <: this.C } }
val o: x.type forSome { val x: c.O.type forSome { val c: C }} =  (new C).O
                                                                         ^
one error found
=================================================================================
val o: C#T = (new C).O
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.C#O.type
 required: _1.O.type forSome { val _1: this.C }
val o: C#T = (new C).O
                     ^
one error found
=================================================================================
val o: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } = { val c = new C; c.O }
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT 2018-04-11:**

Just stumbled upon [this here in 6.4 of the specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html):

> For other expressions `e`, `e.x` is typed as if it was `{ val y = e; y.x }`, for some fresh name `y`.

The parts before this sentence describing the "not-other" expressions seem to refer to ordinary names and stable identifiers. Given this clause in the specification, it is not entirely clear to me why `(new C).O` is not typed in exactly the same way as `{val y = new C; y.O}`, because after this rewriting, the problematic code

```
val o: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } = (new C).O
```

would look just like the only working proposal that I could come up with in the above series of attempts:

```
val o: c.O.type forSome { val c: C } = { val c = new C; c.O }
```

Could the inferred type `C#O.type` actually be a bug, and `c.O.type forSome { val c: C }` be the type mandated by the specification? I wouldn't go so far claiming that it *is* a bug, I'm not familiar enough with the formulations used in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

The object `O` only exists with an instance of `C`, so its type will need to tied with an instance of `C` as well. Hence you can't do `C#O.type` or `C#(O.type)`, but you need to have an instance of `C` first, e.g.:

```
scala> class C { object O }
defined class C

scala> val x = new C
x: C = C@59f95c5d

scala> val y: x.O.type = x.O
y: x.O.type = C$O$@5679c6c6
```

EDIT: Alexey Romanov has commented below that my conclusion is incorrect, which can be demonstrated by this example below:

```
scala> class B { class A {} }
defined class B

scala> val t = new B
t: B = B@63d4e2ba

scala> val u: B#A = new t.A
u: B#A = B$A@1cd072a9
```

So I actually don't know why `B#A` works but `C#O.type` doesn't work :(

Comment: The logic of the first sentence wouldn't change for `class O`: "Every instance of class `O` only exists with an instance of `C`, so its type will need will need to tied with an instance of `C` as well". And it normally is: `c.O`. But the conclusion "Hence you can't do `C#O`" would be of course incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my conclusion. I'll make an edit to my answer :)